# how to check my tex distribution and how to install packages?

Tags: packages, texstudio

I'm using fedora 16, and I use texstudio for compiling tex sources.

Now I want to install caption package, but I'm at a loss on how to install it.

I tried tlmgr on command line, but it prompots: `tlmgr: command not found...`

so how to check my tex distribution and how to install packages?

thanks

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but you did install a TeX distribution right? Fedora 16 doesn't come with TeXLive out of the box. Just checking.

Comment: @Sam Whited yes, I'm just at a loss on how to check the Tex distribution. If there is no TexLive, what my texstudio is using?